# Calculate F test when restricting intercept term

Tags: self-study, variance, f-test

Restrict the intercept term, i.e.

[image]

In this case, I want to calculate F-test.

The formula is as follows:

[image]

How can I calculate SSR for restricted version? What is its formula? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of squared residuals (SSR) is calculated by making a prediction $\hat y_i$, subtracting that prediction from the observed value $y_i$, squaring that difference, and then adding up all of these squared differences across all observations.

To calculate the SSR for the reduced model, fit the reduced model, make predictions, subtract those predictions from the observed values, square those differences, and then add up all of the squared differences. This is exactly the same as you would do for the unrestricted model except that you fit the reduced model instead of the unrestricted model.

Comment: you said "To calculate the SSR for the reduced model, fit the reduced model, make predictions, subtract those predictions from the observed values". How can do this by hand (manually)? Can you please write each formula clearly? Thank you.

Comment: @1190 How to calculate the OLS parameter estimates and then make predictions?